# How can I tell a CUPS printer that it can accept multiple copies

Tags: cups, printer

Can print, cannot select "Number of copies" or "Colour/BW"

I have CUPS Google Cloud printer via a Raspberry Pi. It is a industrial printer and uses the <s>Generic PPD</s>* see below. 
How can I tell CUPS that the printer has the "Number of copies" and "Colour/BW" options?

I do not want to set default values, as this seems to be all the documentation refers to, but to let the printer expose these settings to the user. specifically on a Chromebook.

It always prints in Colour (that is not a problem it just seems weird that the option is not exposed).

Edited: I have now installed the manufacture's PPD and filter which gives me 30+ options. On the Chromebook when printing I get the extra options of Stapling, Toner saver plus many others but no "Number of Copies".

Surely this does not need to be printer driver/PPD dependant and CUPS or even the Chrome instance could just send 'n' copies on request.

Comment: I have cups, and i manage this options in printer driver, not necessary to change anything in cups. I have options MaxCopies set to 10 in cupsd.conf, maybe this helps

Comment: Not currently set in cupsd.conf. As far as I can tell setting that value does not affect the end users ability to set the number of copies. Just errors if they go over it. Which makes sense in a client server world.

Comment: It is a Toshiba e-Studio287cs and only after a lot of research did I find that that makes it a "e-STUDIO407CS Series" which has got a dedicated PPD and Filter file.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the Generic PPD does not know how to tell the printer to make multiple copies.

In general, if the printer cannot make multiple copies, you can add the `*cupsManualCopies: true` line into the PPD for that printer, to make CUPS output multiple copies of the print job if multiple copies are requested by the user (therefore making it possible for CUPS to offer the option of multiple copies).

https://www.cups.org/doc/spec-ppd.html#cupsManualCopies

But in the specific case of CUPS printing to/via Google Cloud, you might want to use this instead of the Generic PPD:

https://www.niftiestsoftware.com/cups-cloud-print/

Comment: added that to the PPD and restarted cups and the cloudprint service, removed and re-added the printer to Google Cloud system. No change. I also ran the cupstestppd and it passed. Any other ideas?